# Is the circuit right?

Tags: current, diodes, rectifier, power-electronics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWd9iO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

I have found this questions and the circuit seems worong to me because  the output terminal hasn't end point.

> If we add  a more diode into the circuit will it be explainable? is the circuit has been drawn in a right way??

Answer (score 3):

It would work if the transformer had a center tap and the unused wire was connected there.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flIchE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now it is a full wave rectifier utilizing separate transformer windings wor each half wave. In the old days a transformer with a middle tap was cheaper than adding two extra diodes as used in a [Graetz cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge).

Comment: So the  picture is not right. Now can I ask any question that, if we add more diodes then what would happen ?

Comment: Where would you want to use extra diodes? @zero_field

Comment: Before resistor and before a diode also. what i think the extra diode will not affect any problem because the current due to positive polarity.  And one more question, why the picture was wrong? i mean why do we need to connect as center tapped?

Comment: your picture is wrong because the resistor was only connected on one end, the other end has a loose wire. Can't follow you on the other part of your question.

Comment: I mean if I add  more diodes in any location then will be there any interruption for flowing current?

Comment: @zero_field that depends on location and orientation. More diodes will not improve functionality unless changing to the Graetz cell topology.

Comment: http://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/13/laser_pointer_more_power.png I could not resist

Comment: Current can flow into the diode from p type to n type. and if we don't place diodes  reversely then,  my question is,  why the placement of the more diodes can  affect the current?

Comment: @VladimirCravero You sound like Tim the Toolman Taylor

Comment: Voltage drop across the diode @zero_field. For a regular diode 0.7V or more, depending on current.

Comment: Yippie but he doesn't have a centre tap